# Tree-Grid in ext js don't show the value field correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to use a tree-grid in Ext js 6.5.0, but the field that is marked as xtype: 'treecolumn' is showing the text "root" with a folder icon instead of the given value

The view code:

```
Ext.define('Bonus.view.cycleDetails.TreeGridIcs', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.TreeGridIcs',
itemId: 'treeGrid',
reserveScrollbar: true,
useArrows: true,
rootVisible: true,
multiSelect: true,
singleExpand: true,
style: 'border: 1px solid #d0d0d0',
margin: '10 10 0 10',
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
        text: 'Nome',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'usuario'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',//we must use the templateheader component so we can use a custom tpl
        text: 'item de controle',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'item',
        align: 'center',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',//we must use the templateheader component so we can use a custom tpl
        text: 'Código Item',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'idItemControle',
        align: 'center',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'peso',
        width: 150,
        dataIndex: 'peso',
        sortable: true
    },
  ]
});
```

the method in the controller that adds the data to tree-grid

```
onChangeCombo: function (e) {
    var me = this;
    gerenteId = e.getValue('id');

    if (gerenteId && gerenteId > 0) {
        grid = me.view.down('#treeGrid');
        store = Ext.create('Bonus.store.SubordinadosStore');
        me.view.setLoading(true);
        store.load({
            params: {
                subordinate: gerenteId
            },
            callback: function (store) {
                me.view.setLoading(false);
                if (store) {
                    if (store.length > 0) {
                        var root = new Object();
                        root.sucess = true;
                        root.children = [store[0].data, store[1].data];
                        grid.setRoot(root);
                    } else {
                        grid.getStore().removeAll();
                    }
                } else {
                    grid.getStore().removeAll();
                }
            }
        });
    }
},
```

the data that is added to treegrid in the "root" variable as a json minified:

```
{"sucess":true,"children":[{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":null,"item":null,"leaf":false,"peso":null,"usuario":"Empresa","name":"","id":"Bonus.model.AdministratorsModel-1"},{"cargo":null,"children":[{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118188,"item":"# gestores abajo del nivel","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1151719,"item":"% de metas logradas","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1216870,"item":"%","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1216871,"item":"%","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1216873,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1221461,"item":"% RR Realizadas / total","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1227158,"item":"%","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1227159,"item":"%","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1233084,"item":"Numero de usuarios","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1117245,"item":"Controle da Rotina","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189511,"item":"# de gestores nivel inferior al esperado","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189512,"item":"% de metas logradas","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189513,"item":"# de reuniones realiadas de los Líderes Soportados","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118221,"item":"% de metas logradas","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118815,"item":"Cantidad de clientes activos 30 días","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118817,"item":"Cantidad de usuarios últimos 30 días","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146415,"item":"#","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146418,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146448,"item":"Usuarios registrados acumulado","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146453,"item":"Usuarios Registrados Acumulados","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146483,"item":"#","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146485,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146627,"item":"Total de PDV de agentes con material POP convergente. ","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118239,"item":"$","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118810,"item":"# de nuevos hogares","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118812,"item":"# de abonados Postpago","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1118814,"item":"# de recargas","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146486,"item":"%","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1146686,"item":"#","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1151687,"item":"# de gestores nivel inferior al esperado","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1151751,"item":"# de reuniones realizadas","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189773,"item":"# de gestores nivel inferior al esperado","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189774,"item":"% de metas logradas","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189775,"item":"# de reuniones realiadas de los Líderes Soportados","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1189999,"item":"# de gestores nivel inferior al esperado","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1190000,"item":"% de metas logradas","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1190001,"item":"# de reuniones realiadas de los Líderes Soportados","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201170,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201172,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201174,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201376,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201377,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201378,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201379,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1201380,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1205968,"item":"Cantidad","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1216853,"item":"Peor Color","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1216857,"item":"Peor Color","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1217133,"item":"Nota de EGU","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1221462,"item":"% media de EGU de los usuarios","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1230893,"item":"$","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1233080,"item":"No. de Usuarios","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1233081,"item":"No. de Usuarios ","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1246294,"item":"Encuesta","leaf":true,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":[{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1246294,"item":"(RADAR) Orientación De Equipo MTD Cultura Organizacional","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":null}],"idItemControle":null,"item":null,"leaf":false,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO"},{"cargo":null,"children":[{"cargo":null,"children":null,"idItemControle":1246297,"item":"(RADAR) Orientación De Equipo MTD Cultura Organizacional","leaf":true,"peso":0,"usuario":null}],"idItemControle":null,"item":null,"leaf":false,"peso":null,"usuario":"SANCHEZ PRIETO JUAN JOSE"}],"idItemControle":null,"item":null,"leaf":false,"peso":null,"usuario":"MARQUEZ PULIDO RODRIGO","name":"","id":"Bonus.model.AdministratorsModel-2"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

"showing the text "root" with a folder icon instead of the given value" I could not see a "given value" in your code. But if you want to change the "Root" to something else you can change your code to the following.
Try the following:

```
onChangeCombo: function (e) {
    var me = this;
    gerenteId = e.getValue('id');

    if (gerenteId && gerenteId > 0) {
        grid = me.view.down('#treeGrid');
        store = Ext.create('Bonus.store.SubordinadosStore');
        me.view.setLoading(true);
        store.load({
            params: {
                subordinate: gerenteId
            },
            callback: function (store) {
                me.view.setLoading(false);
                if (store) {
                    if (store.length > 0) {
                        /*var root = new Object();
                        root.sucess = true;
                        root.children = [store[0].data, store[1].data];
                        grid.setRoot(root);*/
/// I HAVE ADDED THIS CODE --------------------------------------------------
                        grid.setRoot({
                            usuario: "Another Root Name",
                            children: [
                                store[0].data,
                                store[1].data
                            ]
                        });
// TILL HERE -----------------------------------------------------------------
                    } else {
                        grid.getStore().removeAll();
                    }
                } else {
                    grid.getStore().removeAll();
                }
            }
        });
    }
},
```

If you want to **hide root node** you can use "rootVisible: false" in your tree panel.